# How can I GET youtube video title with httr request?

Tags: r

I'm not a programer so I might be tripping onto something really silly to solve.

I'm trying to get the title of multiple youtube videos for my research. I recently found the httr package, and I think the GET function reaches this info really well, the problem is that I don't know how to access the response.

I tried

```
x <- GET("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo")

content(x)
```

and it gave me this response

```
{html_document}
<html style="font-size: 10px;font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" lang="pt-BR" system-icons="" typography="" typography-spacing="">
[1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<meta http ...
[2] <body>\n<div id="watch7-content" class="watch-main-col" itemscope itemid="" itemtype="h ...
```

I know that every video title is in [1]<head'> part as:

<title= TITLE OF THE VIDEO - YOUTUBE </'title>

or  as

<'meta name="title" content=" TITLE OF THE VIDEO ">

Is that a way to browse the content response to extract this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach that can be considered  :

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

vector_URL_Title_To_Extract <- c("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyX5RFSxWOY",
                                 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo",
                                 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndTktsXlN7w")

nb_URL <- length(vector_URL_Title_To_Extract)
list_URL_Names <- list()

for(i in 1 : nb_URL)
{
  print(i)
  webpage <-  read_html(vector_URL_Title_To_Extract[i])
  webpage_Text <- html_text(webpage)
  title <- stringr::str_extract_all(webpage_Text, "(;[^;]*#YouTubeRewind - YouTube)|(;[^;]*- YouTube\\{)")[[1]]
  list_URL_Names[[i]] <- title
}

list_URL_Names

[[1]]
[1] ";CAQ celebrates victory in Quebec City, as opposition absorbs loss in Montreal - YouTube{"

[[2]]
[1] ";YouTube Rewind 2019: For the Record | #YouTubeRewind - YouTube"

[[3]]
[1] ";Crazy Capoeira Master Setting the UFC on Fire - Michel Pereira - YouTube{"
```

Comment: Thank you for presenting me the "rvest" package! it was perfect for what I needed.

Comment: I suggest you add your solution in the tread to help the community.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would probably be using [YouTube's API designed for this purpose](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos)

But if you know the format of the youtube page's HTML you could probably just represent the whole HTML document as a string and use a string function to find the index of where the title tag is located, and isolate it that way. Or you could use a HTML parser to parse the HTML and find the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that can be considered :

```
library(RSelenium)
port <- as.integer(4444L + rpois(lambda = 1000, 1))
rd <- rsDriver(chromever = "105.0.5195.52", browser = "chrome", port = port)
remDr <- rd$client

vector_URL_Title_To_Extract <- c("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyX5RFSxWOY",
                                 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo",
                                 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndTktsXlN7w")

nb_URL <- length(vector_URL_Title_To_Extract)
list_URL_Names <- list()

for(i in 1 : nb_URL)
{
  print(i)
  remDr$navigate(vector_URL_Title_To_Extract[i])
  Sys.sleep(5)
  web_Obj <- remDr$findElement("css selector", '#title > h1 > yt-formatted-string')
  list_URL_Names[[i]] <- web_Obj$getElementText()
}

list_URL_Names

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "CAQ celebrates victory in Quebec City, as opposition absorbs loss in Montreal"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "YouTube Rewind 2019: For the Record | #YouTubeRewind"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "Crazy Capoeira Master Setting the UFC on Fire - Michel Pereira"
```